# Office PIA error in Visual Studio (SSDT): Class not registered

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio-2010, ssis

We have a SQL Server 2012 SSIS package running in which there is a C# script task which has the following configuration. Initially it was error with not able to detect Office in the namespace, which is gone after I added two references EXCELPIA and EXCEELPOL. Than also there was an error like "Cannot find Policy.11.0.Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.config". So what I did is renamed Policy.12.0.Microsoft.Office.Interop.MSPROJECT.config as the following and Visual Studio build it successfully. :D

*But now I am having problem during execution like, "Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {00024500-0000-0000-C000-000000000046} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."*

Kindly dont recommend installing Office as it was running successfully without office earlier.

Kindly help me, as I am not a C#/VS expert and took the job seeing SSDT. Pls,

Here are the readOnlyvariables for the Script task: 
User::FileNameExistsPDF,User::FileNameExportPDF,User::FolderPathExistsPDF,User::FolderPathExportPDF

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;


namespace ST_7843d274ed184dd59c75bb80b70ab856
{

                public void Main()
                {

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application excelApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
            Workbook excelWorkBook = null;



            string paramSourceBookPath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPathExistsPDF"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::FileNameExistsPDF"].Value.ToString();
                        object paramMissing = Type.Missing;



            string paramExportFilePath = Dts.Variables["User::FolderPathExportPDF"].Value.ToString() + Dts.Variables["User::FileNameExportPDF"].Value.ToString();
            XlFixedFormatType paramExportFormat = XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF;
            XlFixedFormatQuality paramExportQuality = XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard;
            bool paramOpenAfterPublish = false;
            bool paramIncludeDocProps = true;
            bool paramIgnorePrintAreas = true;
            object paramFromPage = Type.Missing;
            object paramToPage = Type.Missing;


            try
            {
                // Open the source workbook.
                excelWorkBook = excelApplication.Workbooks.Open(paramSourceBookPath,
                    paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                    paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                    paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing, paramMissing,
                    paramMissing, paramMissing);

                // Save it in the target format.
                if (excelWorkBook != null)
                    excelWorkBook.ExportAsFixedFormat(paramExportFormat,
                        paramExportFilePath, paramExportQuality,
                        paramIncludeDocProps, paramIgnorePrintAreas, paramFromPage,
                        paramToPage, paramOpenAfterPublish,
                        paramMissing);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // Respond to the error.
            }
            finally
            {
                // Close the workbook object.
                if (excelWorkBook != null)
                {
                    excelWorkBook.Close(false, paramMissing, paramMissing);
                    excelWorkBook = null;
                }

                // Quit Excel and release the ApplicationClass object.
                if (excelApplication != null)
                {
                    excelApplication.Quit();
                    excelApplication = null;
                }

                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
                GC.Collect();
                GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
            }  
                        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
                }


        enum ScriptResults
        {
            Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
            Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
        };
        #endregion

        }
}
```

Comment: well, it seems like you are using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` so you definitely do need Office installed.

Comment: I am new to the project, but the guys here told me it was running without office!!!

Comment: I think that you can avoid installing office by installing the [Access database drivers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255).  Could you check if these were installed on a machine in which this package last worked?

Comment: If "the guys here told me it was running without office", then you should ask the guys to fix it since they're clearly experts

Comment: Hi Mark, Yes, Access DB eninge is already installed.